# How to write pseudocode in LaTeX in Google Colab

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I want to render in my colab some pseudocode, say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{A simple algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{MyAlgorithm}{}
\State $x \gets 0$
\While{$x < 10$}
\State $x \gets x + 1$
\EndWhile
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

How can I render this pseudocode in Latex in Google Colab?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: @JamesT Sure, sorry. Just edited.